# What are the numbers on the character descriptions?

Tags: ascendant

On the character selection screen, there is a number sequence displayed in the character description.  It appears to be a combination of 2 and 1, but I only have two characters unlocked so far.

What do these numbers mean?

[image: Memnon - 2 2 1]
[image: Theseus - 1 2 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those numbers are the slots available for using Blessings. The left number is the number of weapon slots, the middle number is the number of body slots, and the right number is the number of magic slots.